# In Go, what are the best practices to find open socket/file descriptors leaks?

Tags: http, go, proxy

Consider the following code of a small proxy server.

It uses its own client configuration to disable TLS certificates
checks.

```
func ProxyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tlsconfig := &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsconfig}
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        },
    }

    r.RequestURI = ""
    queryURL := "https://upstream.server/"

    u, err := url.Parse(queryURL)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Println("proxy error:", err)
    }
    r.URL = u

    resp, err := client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Println("proxy error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    copyHeader(w.Header(), resp.Header)
    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
}
```

The code has a connections leak here, i.e. after some running time the proxy has tons of open connections.

The reason seems to be creation of the transport for each connection, and the problem can be fixed with deferring `client.CloseIdleConnections()` after the client initialization.

Contrary to closing connections, deferring this call is not so well-known, and so I expect that the mistake that I did here can occur pretty often.

My questions:

1. Is my assumption correct, and we always should defer CloseIdleConnections() call after client initialization? (provided we don't reuse the same transport)? Or is it wrong?
2. What is the standard best practices approach, to search for connection/descriptors leaks in Go?

Comment: an `http.Transport` is meant to be reused, not discarded after every request.

Comment: The very first part of the docs says: _"By default, Transport caches connections for future re-use. This may leave many open connections when accessing many hosts. This behavior can be managed using Transport's CloseIdleConnections method and the MaxIdleConnsPerHost and DisableKeepAlives fields.

Transports should be reused instead of created as needed. Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines."_

Comment: @JimB: Yes, I saw it already, you missed my update, I believe; but even though if it is meant to be reused, is it a reason to produce "leaks"? I mean, what is the problem if I just create so many transports as I will?

Comment: @DanielFarrell: That's how it is usually being done. Or you mean it is possible to get an error and an open connection at the same time?

Comment: The reason it "leaks" is stated in the documentation I quoted, _"Transport caches connections for future re-use. This may leave many open connections when accessing many hosts"_, you cannot have an efficient http transport without keeping connections open, so you have to expect these to be somehow associated with the transport.

Comment: @JimB: I still don't get it: if the client does not exist anymore, why the connections are still open? And if it exists, should I deallocate the client explicitly? (I understand the point with the single client etc; thank you for that, it was helpful; but now let us clarify the question with the client deallocation; let's imagine that I need a new client each time; should I deallocate explicitly then to avoid "leaks"?)

Comment: There is no such thing as explicit "deallocation" in Go, it is a garbage collected language. If you want to explicitly release the resources use by the transport, you do what the documentation says and call `CloseIdleConnections`. If you want to prevent idle connections, again the documentation covers that and you have `DisableKeepAlives`. (side note you also are missing a bunch of default values on the Transport. If you really do have a use for a new Transport each time, it would be better to `Clone()` the default)

Comment: @JimB: I understand it of course, but the question is why the client was not collected by the garbage collector? How I understand it: you create the client (no matter for what reason), the client creates connections, then the outer function exits; the client must be marked for the garbage collection, and collected later, and its resources must be freed. But it does not happen. And my question is why

Comment: My bad,  i was thinking `r.Body`, but the code says `resp.Body`.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: That's fine!

Comment: The transport is not collected precisely because it contains active connections. Garbage collection reuses unreachable memory, it is not concerned with determining whether you are logically done using a network socket, and it definitely does not interrupt waiting gorouitnes.

Comment: @JimB: Yes, I understand all of this. That's you who brought garbage collection into the discussion, not me. My question still remains: why if the HTTP query was handled and closed (see the code), the client still remains "active" and "not deallocated" and keeps spare idle connections, which results in literally 100k "spare" connection in short period of time. Is it really how it is expected to work?

Comment: If you’re not confused about garbage collection, or the docs, I’m afraid I don’t understand what you’re asking. Implementing HTTP requires maintaining idle connections, if you don’t want those for some reason, you can close them or disable them.

Comment: @JimB: I want to say, I don't understand why client is keeping the connections, even after the function is finished, and client is out of scope, not referenced by anyone. Should I explicitly terminate the client if I don't need it anymore?

Comment: The client is irrelevant, the transport maintains the connections. The transport keeps the connections open, because that is its job— to implement http which requires keeping connections open. There is no way to explicitly terminate a transport, because it’s supposed to be long lived. If you do need to discard the transport, the documentation clearly states that you can use `CloseIdleConnections` to close the cached connections (or prevent them entirely via the other options)

Comment: @JimB: Why the client keeps 100k idle connections (and the number is growing fast) to the same upstream server? Does it make sense? Is it the desired behaviour? WHy can't it just reuse the same idle connections?

Comment: The client does not keep 100k idle connections, all the the transports you created do. You are accumulating connections because you discard a new transport on _every single request_, each of which is holding the connection open for future requests, because that is how HTTP is specified to work. There is a reason the default client always uses a single `http.DefaultTransport`, it should always be re-used. If you do not want to reuse the transport for some reason, disable idle connections or close them.

Comment: @JimB: The longer we have this discussions, the more I come to understanding, it is as it is and you don't want to see any problem in the fact, that orphaned transports have idle connections

Comment: Of course I'm only describing the current `net/http` package and the Go language, since that is what you are using. There's no point in debating here how else the language may have been designed, or the std library architected.

Comment: @JimB: You posted a very good link about nil values returned with non-nil errors, but DanielFarrell removed his erroneous comment, and you removed the link. Now I need this link, and can't find it. Could you please share it again?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t remember what it was, but I usually only link to the official language docs. Do you have any more details about the question?

Comment: This argument you two had has helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: What i think happened is that since you are constructing the Transport yourself, Go is setting the rest of the struct fields to their zero value. At least for me this was causing issues as the max idle and max connections defaulted to 0 (no limit)